# YOLOv8 predict memory allocation

Tags: python, image, prediction, yolo, yolov8

There is an endpoint with YoloV8 predictions.

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
yolo_model = YOLO('myownyolo.pt')
```

Each of the requests increases memory usage by 40-250 mb on this line call.

`for result in yolo_model.predict(image_data, conf=0.50, stream=True):`

```
 391.7 MiB      0.0 MiB    - before predict call                                              
 602.7 MiB    209.8 MiB    - after predict call
# each next request starts from prev memory count and reached the limit to OOM Killed Memory
```

I have tried these, but it doesn't help at all

```
    del result
    del image_data
    gc.collect()
```

Another StackOverflow topic says to import keras and use :

```
    K.clear_session()
```

Comment: Can you try to specify the GPU directly as [recommended in this guide](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/cdb10563d2a0c7ac032aa6abcc79bd6130ca7a04/docs/en/guides/yolo-common-issues.md#gpu-deployment-issues)? You can pass the device option to the `predict` method. The value should correlate with the indexes of the gpu e.g. `yolo_model.predict(image_data, conf=0.50, stream=True, device=','.join(map(str, range(ultralytics.utils.checks.cuda_device_count())) if ultralytics.utils.checks.cuda_device_count() > 0 else 'cpu'))`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule, there isn't available gpu at device. It runs always on CPU. 
The main problem is that memory is not deallocated after processing of the result

Comment: What is the size of `image_data`? Are you making predictions on a single image, small batch of images or multiple images?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule, `predict_image(file: UploadFile = File(...)) img_data = await file.read()`. It's a single image uploaded to the server. Size of images from 60-100 kB up to 1Mb

Comment: Is there a difference in memory allocation when using `stream=False`?

Comment: @hanna_liavoshka, yep, it looks like less memory is used. But anyway it doesn't deallocate even after `results.clear()`or `del results` call. Each prediction result saves allocated memory and is stuck with it until limits to application restart.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this behavior on the Colab CPU by printing the model result on different images in a loop. Memory allocation is pretty stable. Perhaps more information about the model scale (n, s, m, l ,x), task (detection, segmentation..), and what you do in a loop can clarify the cause of the problem. Testing your script in Colab can exclude the environmental issue.